# Rails: Transfer files via API

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I want to transfer a large files (100 - 200 Mb) (or raw data) from iOS to Rails server (via some API). Files maybe aren't very large, but the transfer's speed can be low. What approach should I use? Should I use websockets? Or just split file on iOS into smaller chunks and transfer chunk after chunk? I would like to be able to monitor if whole file was successfully transfered. And resume transferring in case of Internet connection lost.

Comment: I think you should leave Rails out of this. Upload file to a server, using a tool to handle file transfers, maybe FTP, maybe something else. Let Rails and your API know when the file transfer is completed and a URL or path to get the file.